# How to replace text in HTML using JavaScript without refreshing everything around it?

Tags: javascript, html, replace, discord

I made this simple line of JavaScript that just searches the HTML for a certain link and then replaces it with another, it works as intended but it refreshes everything around it.., quite literally breaking everything around it.

```js
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/src="https:\/\/media.discordapp.net\/attachments/g, 'src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments');
```

I expected it to just replace the links and that is it... not refresh everything around it, making my solution useless. I've spent hours trying to find a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats because you are replacing the entire innerHTML with another. Instead you should look just for the images that have the src attribute you are looking for and replace it with that you need:

```
var images = document.querySelectorAll('img[src^="https://media.discordapp.net/attachments"]');

images.forEach(function(image) {
  image.src = image.src.replace('https://media.discordapp.net/attachments', 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments');
});
```